# Swift "String is not convertible to 'MirorDisposition'" error

Tags: arrays, string, swift

```
 NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())
        {
            (response, data, error) in
            var isResponsable = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            var array = self.JSONParseArray(isResponsable)

            println(array[0]) //Print 1

            if(array[0] == 1) //Get error: String is not convertible to 'MirorDisposition'
            {

            }
            else{

            }
    }
```

JSONParseArray function:

```
func JSONParseArray(jsonString: String) -> Array<String> {
    var e: NSError?
    var data: NSData!=jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    var jsonObj = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(
        data,
        options: NSJSONReadingOptions(0),
        error: &e) as Array<String>
    if e == 0 {
        return Array<String>()
    } else {
        return jsonObj
    }
}
```

My problem is that when i check if array[0] == 1 i get the error: String is not convertible to 'MirrorDisposition'

But if i try: println(array[0]) it print 1

Help please

Comment: Are you sure array[0] doesn't contain the "1" string instead of an Int?

Comment: Thx i did not saw that

Comment: Would you mind if I add that as my answer, so to be rewarded for solving the problem once you accept is as the solution? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have to check whether array[0] doesn't contain the "1" string instead of an integer value